# I am new at this and am trying to figure out how to use timers and loops. I am trying to loop this with a timer. Can you help me?

Tags: python, loops, timer, python-2.x

```
for i in xrange(5):
  abc()
  time.sleep(3)
  print('?~~~~~')
  print('~?~~~~')
  print('~~?~~~')
  print('~~~?~~')
  print('~~~~?~')
  print('~~~~~?')
  print('?~~~~~')
  print('~?~~~~')
  print('~~?~~~')
  print('~~~?~~')
  print('~~~~?~')
  print('~~~~~?')
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: The topic is interesting, but I think you should elaborate your question, and specify what exactly you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I am assuming that you want to move the question mark along the line as the timer advances, with a three second gap in between.

This code nearly needs to be rewritten completely. Don't fret, it's not too bad and it's easy to fix.

The first thing that is wrong here is that you haven't imported your time module for `time.sleep()`. To do this you must simply add at the top of the code `import time`. Secondly, you do not need to use `abs()` in your code, and Python doesn't understand it. Thirdly, when you use a for loop, or any loop for that matter, it executes the whole thing one iteration, then goes back to the start for the next, so your timer is just printing all of that every time it goes through. It does not wait to make it flow, it just prints a block of the tildes every three seconds.
At your current level, I would use a simple if and a variable to test for which iteration it is, because you might not know how to splice yet. Here it is:

```
import time # importing time so time.sleep() works properly
iteration = 1 # Code to tell where the question mark is
for i in xrange(5):
    time.sleep(3)
    if iteration == 1: # asking if the variable is 1
        print('?~~~~~') # printing this
        iteration += 1 # adding one to the iteration variable
    elif iteration == 2:
        print('~?~~~~')
        iteration += 1
    elif iteration == 3:
        print('~~?~~~')
        iteration += 1
    elif iteration == 4:
        print('~~~?~~')
        iteration += 1
    elif iteration == 5:
        print('~~~~?~')
        iteration += 1
    elif iteration == 6:
        print('~~~~~?')
        iteration = 1
```

Here is the version using splicing

```
import time
iteration = 1
list = list('~~~~~~')
old_list = list
for i in xrange(5):
    time.sleep(3)
    list[iteration-1] = '?'
    print("".join(list))
    list = list('~~~~~~')
    if iteration == 6:
        iteration = 1
    else:
        iteration += 1
```

If you want a tutorial, that I would recommend is the one at http://tutorialspoint.com/python/

Otherwise, the original Python tutorial is great: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/